# Arcane Background: Backlash on a roll on "1"?

Tags: savage-worlds

A lot of the Arcane Backgrounds something happens on a roll of '1' on your Spellcasting die. I originally read this to mean that only if your total was a natural '1', i.e. your first roll was a natural '1' then the bad stuff happens.

I heard that at least one other referee takes this to mean, a '1' even if you rolled it on an Ace. For example, say you have Spellcasting d8 and you rolled 8,8,1 then yes you get a success and 3 raises but you also get a backlash.

Is this how it is meant to be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My understanding is that this only applies if it is a natural 1 on the spell casting die.  I don't think it would be classed as 'natural' if the die has aced.

Comment: Clint Black agrees with your answer, http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=324082#324082 hence your answer is blessed as the correct one ;)